# How i can get the first match in regex and import this match in a string?

Tags: c#, regex

For example using a regex expression  **del(.*?)del**  get delcatdel
and save  the result in string  or in  text

word1word2**delcatdel**word3word4**deldogdel**word5

in my text (or string) i need obtain  **delcatdel**

USING c sharp

please anybody help me

Comment: Use `Regex.Match`

Comment: There are 155982 questions about regex. Didn't anyone help you?

Comment: I did not find a similar answer, I was somewhat confused

Comment: `I did not find a similar answer`   **`:)`**  ...........

Comment: I found a similar answer in some 8 seconds - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18544928/3832970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex("del(.*?)del");
var match = regex.Match("word1word2delcatdelword3word4deldogdelword5");
string matched = match.Value;
```