# How to get a part of a string (url)?

Tags: c#

I have the following url

```
http://example.com/pa/TaskDetails.aspx?Proj=A5AF5C0D-648A-4892-A995-CDA8013F2643&Assn=2A992D9C-C511-E611-80E4-005056A13B51
```

I need to extract the `A5AF5C0D-648A-4892-A995-CDA8013F2643` portion of the url parameter:

```
Proj=A5AF5C0D-648A-4892-A995-CDA8013F2643
```

This can be in the middle or at the end of the url. I cannot guarantee the position of it. But i always starts with `Proj=` and end with `&`. The string between this is what i want. How can i grab this within C#?

Comment: Use regular expression of C# to extract any text within Proj= and &.

Comment: RegEx is magic for me. I never understood how the curious combination of chars works :)

Comment: There is an answer for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create a `Uri` and pass the value of its `Query` property to the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method:

```
string value = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri("http://example.com/pa/TaskDetails.aspx?Proj=A5AF5C0D-648A-4892-A995-CDA8013F2643&Assn=2A992D9C-C511-E611-80E4-005056A13B51").Query)["Proj"];
```

The method is defined in System.Web.dll by the way so you need to add a reference to this one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to retrieve the IDFA from a url address. I think you can easily do that by applying regular expressions to the url string. 
For example, the following:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][[0-9a-fA-F]{12}
```

Picks up every valid IDFA when applied to the URL string. You can add conditions for the head and tail of the IDFA to retrieve exactly what you are looking for:

```
Proj=[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][[0-9a-fA-F]{12}&
```

You can test the above Regex (regular expression) syntax on one of the many free online Regex applets (e.g. https://regex101.com/)

To apply Regex to your code, please see the following thread:
[c# regex matches example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740984/c-sharp-regex-matches-example)

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```
string param = HttpUtility
.ParseQueryString("http://example.com/pa/TaskDetails.aspx?Proj=A5AF5C0D-648A-4892-A995-CDA8013F2643&Assn=2A992D9C-C511-E611-80E4-005056A13B51")
.Get("Proj");
```

Comment: So easy? I cant believe this :) i will try it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
string som = "http://example.com/pa/TaskDetails.aspx?Proj=A5AF5C0D-648A-4892-A995-CDA8013F2643&Assn=2A992D9C-C511-E611-80E4-005056A13B51";
int startPos = som.LastIndexOf("Proj=") + "Proj=".Length + 1;
int length = som.IndexOf("&") - startPos;
string sub = som.Substring(startPos, length); //<- This will return your key
```

This should do it.