# RegEx for matching special chars in between two numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match before and after a specific string. 
I have the string `10&#160;990 Points`
But only want to match everything before and after `&#160;`

Ive tried `.+?(?=&#160;)`, but that only takes everything before `&#160;`.

I expect the output of `10&#160;990 Points` To be "10990 Points"

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Pris: " +
    Regex.Match(
        ProductListItem.Descendants("span")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
        .Equals("item-card-details-price-amount")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText
, @"([0-9]+)(&#160;)([A-z\s0-9]+)"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do so. You can simply use capturing groups for doing that, such as [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/yrCXlu/1/):

```
(.*)(\")([\"\w\s0-9]+)(\")(.*)
```

[image]

---

#### Edit:

For your special input, you might use [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/yOYRAT/1):

```
([0-9]+)(&#160;)([A-z\s0-9]+)
```

You might use <kbd>\</kbd> for escaping any metachars based on language specific requirements. If you wish, you can add or reduce boundaries.

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how it works:

[image]

#### Replacement

You can simply use a string replace and replace your input string with '$1$3'.

Comment: [Regexr Test](https://regexr.com/4dd3t)
For me it matches the whole string

Comment: How do i do this in c#? I added my code. Thanks for the super fast replies!

Comment: Checked it [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740984/c-sharp-regex-matches-example) you sent. And this is what i did. Does not work
```c#
Console.WriteLine("Pris: " +
    Regex.Match(
        ProductListItem.Descendants("span")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
        .Equals("item-card-details-price-amount")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText
, @"([0-9]+)(&#160;)([A-z\s0-9]+)", "&1&3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the pattern `.+?(?=&#160;)` only matches what is in front of `&#160;` is because `(?=` is a positive lookahead assertion that does not consume any characters.

If you want to match all before `&#160;` and the rest after you could use 2 capturing groups instead of 3 because you don't need the match for `&#160;` itself.

In the replacement use the 2 groups `$1$2`

```
(.+?)&#160;(.+)
```

That will match

- `(.+?)` Capturing group 1, match 1+ chars except an newline non greedy
- `&#160;` Match `&#160;`
- `(.+)` Capturing group 2, match 1+ chars except an newline

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%2b%3f%29%26%23160%3b%28.%2b%29&i=10%26%23160%3b990+Points&r=%241%242)

If you want to match the digits `([0-9]+)` only, your code might look like:

```
Regex.Replace("10&#160;990 Points", @"([0-9]+)&#160;(.*)", m => m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value)
```

**Note**

In this character class `[A-z\s0-9]+` this part `A-z` [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than the ranges `a-z` and `A-Z`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Using the

```
([0-9]+)(&#160;)([A-z\s0-9]+)
```

In c#, I used

```
Regex.Replace(string, @"([0-9]+)(&#160;)([A-z\s0-9]+)", m => m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[3].Value)
```

`m.Groups[1].Value` and `m.Groups[3].Value` are the groups in Regex.Match, these get replaced. You can see it working [here.](https://rextester.com/MRAK79352)