# How to extract a value in string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
string str = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"376\" height=\"254\" viewBox=\"0 0 376 254\">"
```

How to extract the value of height?

Anything like `height=\"%\"`in `regex`?

Comment: Please, share what have you tried so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# regex matches example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740984/c-sharp-regex-matches-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string str = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"376\" height=\"254\" viewBox=\"0 0 376 254\">";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\bheight="")[^""]*");
Match match = regex.Match(str);
string height = match.Value; // = "254"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that \ is a special escape character. This works:

```
string str = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"376\" height=\"254\" viewBox=\"0 0 376 254\">";
string temp = Regex.Match(str, "height=\"\\d+\"").Value;   //height=254
int height =Int32.Parse (Regex.Match(temp, "\\d+").Value); //254
```